# Прототипы. Наследование. Запись обработчиков событий

Tags: jquery, наследование, javascript, события

Всем привет! Возможно вопрос будет сумбурным и глупым, но все же стоит его задать.
Я хочу разобраться с наследованием в `JavaScript`. Но все статьи и примеры о нем говорят только о св-вах и методах. Например:

```
function Animal() {};
Animal.prototype.run = function() {
    console.log('run');
}

function Cat(){};
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

var petya = new Cat();
petya.run(); // "run"
```

Тут все просто и понятно. 
Но я хочу, например,  конструктор кнопок с методом log (выводит в консоль "123"). А потом сделать еще один конструктор, на основе первого, который имеет, в добавок к первому, свой метод log2 (выводит в консоль "456").

```
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>

<script>
    function Button(elem){}

    Button.prototype.log = function() {
        console.log('123');
    }

    function Button2(elem){}

    Button2.prototype = Object.create(Button.prototype);
    Button2.prototype.log2 = function() {
        console.log('456');
    }

    var btn1 = new Button( document.getElementById('btn1') );
    var btn2 = new Button2( document.getElementById('btn2') );
</script>
```

Вот скажите куда мне писать обработчик `onclick`, в котором будут вызывать `log`, `log2`? В конструктор, в прототип, или куда то еще?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример немного более близкий к оригинальному:

```
function Button(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', this.log);
}

Button.prototype.log = function () {
    console.log('123');
};

function Button2(elem) {
    Button.apply(this, arguments);
}
Button2.prototype = Object.create(Button.prototype);
Button2.prototype.log = function () {
    console.log('456');
};
window.onload = function () {
    var btn1 = new Button(document.getElementById('btn1'));
    var btn2 = new Button2(document.getElementById('btn2'));
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/5ugRF/

Суть в следующем - непонятно зачем тащить новый метод log2 если можно перезадать старый. тогда, мы просто задаем один раз конструктор, который вешает событие на `this.log` и с пом-ю apply меняем ему контекст выполнения.

Comment: "который имеет, в добавок к первому, свой метод log2 (выводит в консоль "456")"
Метод log это просто пример. Там могло бы быть wwfwf3wwwf. Суть в том что мы добавляем новый метод, а не затираем старый...
Ну в общем, если я правильно понял, то обработчики лучше вешать в конструкторе и от туда вызывать метода прототипа?

Comment: вы поняли не правильно.

конструктор это единственное место откуда можно вызывать функции вешающие обработчики.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант вам подходит?

```
function Button(elem) {
   elem.onclick = function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    return false;
  };
}

var btn1 = new Button(document.getElementById('btn1'));
```

Comment: А где прототипы?)) Тогда можно писать просто:

document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function() {
    много-много текста кода
}

Comment: У меня ощущение, что вы не с той стороны заходите. А чем будет отличаться ваш код, если вы на две кнопки написали две функции и два прототипа для этой функции? Напишите, чего вы хотите достигнуть.

Comment: ну и еще такой момент, вешать событие естественно в конструкторе надо, ибо это единственная функция выполняющаяся при new()